# Nested objects referring to each other?

Tags: javascript, oop

Suppose I have something like this:

```
network = {
  post: function(t) {
    console.log(t); }
  protocol: {
    init: function() {
      /* network.post("init") */ } } }
```

The commented part, how would I allow the network.protocol.init function to call network.post through some sort of relative link? How can network.protocol find networks variables?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of object literal syntax; you just can't do it.

Your best option would be to reference `network` via a property on the `protocol` object, and add it immediately after declaring the object via object literal syntax;

```
network = {
  post: function(t) {
    console.log(t); }
  protocol: {
    init: function() {
      this.network.post("init") } } }

network.protocol.network = network;
```

... this works because the existance of the `network` property is deferred until the execution of `init` itself.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that... I was hoping for something cleaner. Any ideas?

Comment: That's as clean as its going to get I'm afraid. You can of course, set the whole of "protocol" later, instead of just the "network" property. You could then modify the "init" of "protocol" to accept the "network" instance as a parameter.... That might be cleaner.